# clink pagination in he view

Tags: php, html, yii, pagination

i need to add a pagination to my page. Here is my code right now.

Controller:

```
$count=Data::model()->count($criteria);
        $pages=new CPagination($count);


        $pages->params = array(
            'startDate' => $startDate,
            'endDate' => $endDate,
            'id' => $id,
          'asData' => 'asData'
        if (isset($page)) {
            $pages->setCurrentPage($page-1); //stored in $_GET['page']
        }

        // results per page
        $pages->pageSize=10;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
```

View:

```
<?php 

$this->widget('CLinkPager', array(

            'pages' => $pages,
        ));
```

I want to be able to display results and count total number of data also. how can i display it as :

Displaying 1-10 of 67 results.
`<< First < Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 Next > Last >>` instead?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is "probably." Though without more information I can't tell you much more. Is your view a PHP script, or are you using a templating engine?

As long as you can perform mathematical operations in whatever you're using, you should be able to calculate how many pages would be displayed for a total number of results.

Is $pages the total number of pages to display, or the total number of results? If it's the total number of pages, you could just iterate using a counter to output it. If it's the total number of results, I believe the math for that would be the ceiling of the total number of results divided by the number of results per page, or:

```
ceil($pages/10)
```

in your example.

Comment: i am using Yii to generate it. pages is the total number of pages.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't catch that you were using Yii at first. I'm not that familiar with it, but after doing some digging it looks like most people customize their pagers by writing a custom class that extends CLinkPager, which probably isn't doable from the view. However, CLinkPager does have a property called "viewPath." Can you edit the appropriate file in the path that this property points to? If so, can you tell me what the file contents look like?